# Is the G-extension of a fusion category unique?

Tags: ct.category-theory

The definition reads that "A G-extension of a fusion category D is a G-graded fusion category C whose trivial component is equivalent to D."  It seems like a priori there can be multiple G-extensions for the same fusion category D.  Is that really the case (i.e. no reduction mechanism)?  But there seems to be a "canonical one" at least, which has the same category D sitting on top of each component of the grading.  Does this particular G-extension have a name?

Comment: If the words you're using all mean what I think they mean, then no, extensions aren't unique: you can find nonequivalent $G$-extensions of $\text{Vect}$, for example, by twisting the associator by a class in $H^3(G, \mathbb{C}^{\ast})$. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete reference for G-extension of fusion categories is http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3140 (see also http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0881). The kind of examples that you are saying are $\mathcal D\boxtimes \text{Vec}_G$, the Deligne product  of $\mathcal D$ with Vec$_G$.

Comment: Hey, Cesar!  Thanks.  Sorry for being off for a while.  So, we can also twist the Deligne product, I assume.  Let me look a bit more carefully into the reference paper.  But it's always good to be able to just discuss intuitive.  Hope to see you again soon.